# mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in puntosDAE.class.php on line 91

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

El problema ocurre en este archivo php llamado barra_status.php. Lo que ocurre es que la function lectura_dias() no hace nada, no se trae los dias y muestra este error

Este es el archivo padre, dashboard.php. Ya tiene como require barra_status.php y el DAEclass.php.

```
<?php           
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['registro_id'])){
     header("location:index.php");
  }else{
    require("complementos/user_language.php");
    require("function/class/puntosDAE.class.php");
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $user_language; ?>">
    <head>
        <title>Evolution Group</title>
        <link href="images/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <!-- Metas -->
        <?php require("complementos/metas.php"); ?>
        <!-- Metas -->
        <!-- Script -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var registro_id = <?php echo $_SESSION['registro_id']; ?>;
        </script>
        <!-- Script -->
    </head>
    <body onload="mostrardash()">
    <div id="contenido2">
        <!-- Head -->
        <?php require("complementos/head.php"); ?>
        <!-- Head -->
        <!-- Contenido Fluid-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Barra Status -->
            <?php require("complementos/barra_status.php"); ?>
            <!-- Barra Status -->
            <!-- Contenidos -->
            <div id="ContenidoPT">
                <?php 
                    if($_SESSION['registro_nivel'] == 0){
                        require("pantallas/dashboard.pt.php"); 
                    }else if($_SESSION['registro_nivel'] == 1){
                        require("pantallas/dashboard_eaddicted.pt.php"); 
                    }
                ?>
                <?php require("pantallas/instrucciones.pt.php"); ?>
                <?php require("pantallas/catalogo.pt.php"); ?>
                <?php require("pantallas/historial.pt.php"); ?>
                <?php require("pantallas/wallpaper.pt.php"); ?>
                <?php require("pantallas/tarjetas.pt.php"); ?>
            </div>
            <!-- Contenidos -->
        </div>
        <!-- Contenido Fluid -->
        <!-- Footer -->
        <?php require("complementos/footer.php"); ?>
        <!-- Footer -->

        <!-- Modales -->
        <?php require("complementos/modales.php"); ?>
        <!-- Modales -->
        <!-- Links -->
        <?php require("complementos/links.php"); ?>
        <?php require("complementos/links_das.php"); ?>
        <!-- Links -->
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <?php require("complementos/scripts.php"); ?>
        <?php require("complementos/scripts2.php"); ?>
        <!-- Scripts -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Este el archivo barra_status.php, el error ocurre exactamente en lectura_dias y no se trae los dias, simplemente tira ese error que tiene el titulo.

```
require("function/class/puntosDAE.class.php");
<div class="row colstatus">
    <!-- Nombre Semanas Dias -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <span style="text-transform: uppercase;"><b><?php echo $labeldash[0].' '.$_SESSION['registro_nombre'].' '.$_SESSION['registro_apellido']; ?></b></span><br>
        <?php 
        $obj = new iGlobal;
        $obt = $obj -> lectura_dias();
        if($obt) {
            if (mysql_num_rows($obt)<>0){
                while($item = mysql_fetch_array($obt)){   
                    $Dias = $item['dias_id'];
                    $Semanas = $item['dias_semanas'];
                }
            }else{
                    $Dias = "NULL";
                    $Semanas = "NULL";
        }} 
        ?>           
        <span><b><?php echo $labeldash[1]; ?></b></span> <span><?php echo $Semanas; ?><span style="color: #cccccc;">/6</span></span> | 
        <span><b><?php echo $labeldash[2]; ?></b></span> <span><?php echo $Dias; ?><span style="color: #cccccc;">/42</span></span> | <b><?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?></b>
    </div>
    <!-- Nombre Semanas Dias -->
    <!-- EnergyPoint -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <span><b><?php echo $labeldash[3]; ?></b></span> <span id="EnergyPointBS"></span><br>
        <span style='color: #ff0000; font-size: 12px;' id="registro_eliminado"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- EnergyPoint -->
    <!-- Alertas -->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 10px; position: relative; display: inline-block; min-height: 100px; height: auto;">
        <?php 
        $obj = new iGlobal;
        $dates = date("Y-m-d");
        $obt = $obj -> reto_alertas_generales($dates);
        if($obt){
        if (mysql_num_rows($obt)<>0){ 
            while($item = mysql_fetch_array($obt)){ $ag_id = $item['ag_id']; $agv_date = $item['ag_date']; }
            $obj = new iGlobal;
            $dates = date("Y-m-d");
            $obt = $obj -> reto_alertas_generales_vistas($dates, $_SESSION['registro_id']);
            if($obt){
            if (mysql_num_rows($obt)<>0){?>
            <img src="images/alerta_si.png" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 10px;" onclick="alertasVistas();">
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <img src="images/alerta_siActivo.png" class="animated tada" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 10px;" id="alertaA" onclick="alertas_vistas('<?php echo $ag_id; ?>','<?php echo $agv_date; ?>');"> 
            <img src="images/alerta_si.png" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 10px; display: none;" id="alertaD" onclick="alertasVistas();">
        <?php }}}else{ ?>
            <img src="images/alerta_si.png" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 10px;" onclick="alertasVistas();">
        <?php }} ?>
    </div>

    <div style="" class="alertasFlotantes">
        <div class="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; padding: 10px;">
        Notificaciones
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="color: #fff;" onclick="closeAlertas();"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 10px;">
            <?php 
            $dates = date("Y-m-d");
            $obj = new iGlobal;
            $obt = $obj -> muestraAlertas($dates);
            if($obt){
            if (mysql_num_rows($obt)<>0){
            while($item = mysql_fetch_array($obt)){ ?>

            <div class="alertasCont" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <div class="contenidoAlertas"><?php echo $item['ag_mensaje']; ?></div>  
                <div class="contenidoAlertasFechas"><?php echo $item['ag_date']; ?></div>
            </div>

            <?php }}} ?>        
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Alertas -->
</div>
```

Esta es la funcion en PuntosDAEclass.php que tiene que correr ese codigo, pero da el error que puse en el titulo y no consigue ese parametro. Y si coloco PuntosDAEclass.php en barra_status.php, se rompe el css y mas funciones

```
<?php 
include_once("conexion.class.php");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');
class iGlobal{
var $con;
function iGlobal(){
    $this->con=new DBManager;
}

function lectura_dias(){
    $date = date("Y-m-d");          
    if($this->con->con()==true){
        return mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM reto_dias WHERE dias_date = '".$date."' ");
    }
}
```

La conexion con la base de datos si funciona. Edit: Coloque el codigo de esta

```
<?php 
class DBManager{
    public static function con(){
            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            mysqli_select_db($conexion,"agarciac_evolution");

            if(!$conexion){
                return FALSE;

            }else{
                return $conexion;
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: El error dice que la funcion `mysqli_query()` espera 2 parametros, pero solo estas pasando uno.  Necesitas paras la coneccion junto con el query.

Comment: Cierto, si está manejando la conexión con estilo por procedimientos, deberías pasar la conexión como primer parámetro para el `mysqli_query()` y como segundo; la consulta, quedando `mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)`.

Comment: En donde tendria que colocar la conexion?. Me di cuenta que olvide colocar algo mas de codigo en la pregunta

Comment: `if (mysql_num_rows($obt)<>0){` estás usando 2 librerías, `mysql` y `mysqli`, seguramente vas a tener muchos otros problemas luego de solucionar este.

Comment: Ya pase todo a mysqli y sigue con el error

Comment: `return mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM reto_dias WHERE dias_date = '".$date."' ");` aquí estás enviando solo un parámetro (la consulta), falta el recurso de conexión (el que estás creando en DBManager). Consulta el manual si tienes duda dónde debe ir: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php